# Conversion Between DataTable and List

Tags: c#, list, datatable

I have list which contains values of properties and I want to bind this list into my DataTable object.

Comment: Create extension methods... http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/784090/Conversion-Between-DataTable-and-List-in-Csharp

Comment: Do you want to bind list to DataTable ?? or do you mean bind list with gridview or DataGridView or similar control ?

Comment: Put some code in question.

Answer (score 2):

there is an article "Conversion Between DataTable and List in C#" on CodeProject with source code

[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/784090/Conversion-Between-DataTable-and-List-in-Csharp)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you need the result in a DataTable? If you're using the list for databinding, you can do this instead:

```
var people = new List<Person>();
var peopleBinding = new BindingList<Person>(people);
Grid.DataSource = peopleBinding;
```